Is it possible to demonstrate the maximum modulus principle from parseval equality?
The maximum modulus principle says that, if a function $f$ is analytic and not constant in a given domain $D$, then $|f(z)|$ has no maximum value in $D$. That is, there is no point $z_0$ in the domain such that $|f(z)|≤|f(z_0)|$ for all points $z$ in it.
The Parseval equality says that, if $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n$ and if $|z-z_0| = r$ (Here we assume that the series converges absolutely to $|z-z_0| \leq r$),
then
$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} |f(z_0+re^{i\theta})|^2 \, d\theta = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_n|^2r^{2n}.
$
In my book there is an exercise that says that it is possible to obtain the principle of maximum modulus from Parseval equality. Is this even possible? Is it something direct? This exercise appears in the complex integration part, nothing more sophisticated has yet been seen. I don't know how to demonstrate this formally, but it seems to me that the series, which is the result of the integral, should be exactly $|f(z_0)|^2$ and proceed with some argument, such as contradiction. Can you suggest something. Thanks in advance.

Suppose $D\subseteq\mathbb C$ is a domain, and let $f:D\to\mathbb C$ be holomorphic. Suppose there exists some $z_0\in D$ such that $\lvert f(z)\rvert\leq\lvert f(z_0)\rvert$ for all $z\in D$. We will show that $f$ is constant.
Consider the set
$$E=\{z\in D:\lvert f(z)\rvert=\lvert f(z_0)\rvert\}.$$
This is clearly a closed (in $D$) and non-empty. We will show that it is also open, from which it then follows that $E=D$. So take any $z\in E$, and let $R>0$ be such that
$$f(\zeta)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(\zeta-z)^n$$
whenever $\lvert\zeta-z\rvert< R$ (with the series converging absolutely). Let $r\in(0,R)$. Then
$$\lvert f(z_0)\rvert^2=\lvert f(z)\rvert^2=\left\lvert a_0\right\rvert^2\leq\sum_{n=0}^\infty\lvert a_n\rvert^2r^{2n}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\lvert f(z+re^{i\theta})\rvert^2\,\mathrm d\theta\leq\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\lvert f(z_0)\rvert^2\,\mathrm d\theta=\lvert f(z_0)\rvert^2.$$
Consequently
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\lvert\lvert f(z_0)\rvert^2-\lvert f(z+re^{i\theta})\rvert^2\rvert\,\mathrm d\theta=2\pi\lvert f(z_0)\rvert^2-\int_0^{2\pi}\lvert f(z+re^{i\theta})\rvert^2\,\mathrm d\theta=0.$$
This implies that $\lvert f(z+re^{i\theta})\rvert=\lvert f(z_0)\rvert$ for all $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$. As $r$ was arbitrary we have that $\lvert f(\zeta)\rvert=\lvert f(z_0)\rvert$ for all $\zeta\in B_R(z)$, so $B_R(z)\subseteq E$. As $z\in E$ was abitrary, $E$ is open, and hence $E=D$ as it is a non-empty clopen subset of a connected set. Thus $f$ has constant modulus on $D$, and you can check for yourself that this implies that $f$ is constant on $D$ (as $f$ is holomorphic).
